# Why there is gap in array

Tags: modeling

With the mesh created and array added. There is a gap between the mesh.

[image]

[image]

May i know why its getting gap between.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you may mate. It's because this part of your mesh is not straight. In other words, the line between middle of the rectangle and the last vertice of each corner on other levels of the building is a straight line. In the part, where you have the gap, it's not.

Comment: so what is the solution and how to fix it

Comment: The solution below by ivane will fix the gap, but the edges won't be straight then. The ultimate solution would be to move the vertices of the mesh to appropriate position.

Answer (score 0):

Check boxes which are marked with blue line.
And adjust distance value that is marked with red line.
*In screenshot original vertices are selected too but this is just for demonstration purposes. Which also shows that if original mesh is used it can not fit perfectly.*

[image]